# Is it possible to continue executing other tests after pytest-timeout timeouts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

If one of my tests timeouts I receive a timeout message and all other tests are not executed. Is there a way to make pytest continue running other tests after that?

**Edit**

Example:

add.py:

```
import time

def add(a, b):
    if a == 2:
        time.sleep(2)
    elif a == 3:
        time.sleep(4)
    return a + b
```

test_add.py:

```
import pytest
from add import add


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'a, b, expected_result', [
        (1, 1, 2),
        (2, 2, 4),
        (2, 3, 5),
        (3, 2, 5),
        (4, 1, 5)

    ]
)
def test_add(a, b, expected_result):
    result = add(a, b)
    expected_result = a + b
    assert result == expected_result
```

by running

```
(venv) >pytest test_add.py --timeout=3
```

i get

```
============= test session starts ==============
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\calcTest
plugins: timeout-1.4.2
timeout: 3.0s
timeout method: thread
timeout func_only: False
collected 5 items                                                                                                                                                                                           

test_add.py ...
++++++++++++++++++++ Timeout ++++++++++++++++++++


~~~~~~~~~~ Stack of MainThread (10588) ~~~~~~~~~~

  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)

.....
```

The 1st, 2nd and 3rd test were executed, 4th test timeouted and the 5th was not executed. I am looking for a way to run it.

Comment: Provide, please, minimal reproducible example, and how do you run pytest ? Because pytest runs all tests unless you define `-x` or `-maxfail` to stop after failing.

Comment: @AlexNoname I added code example to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pytest-timeout` provieds two timeouts methods: signal and thread.

**Signal** method provides desired functionality, it does not stop entire test suite in case one is failed. But *Windows* does not support the **signal** method and thus it can only use the **thread** method.

As `pytest-timeout` [readme](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout) says:

> **thread**
>
> For each test item the `pytest-timeout` plugin starts a timer thread which will terminate the **whole process** after the specified timeout.

So this is expected behaviour for *Windows*. And, as far as I know, a satisfactory workaround [has not yet been made](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout/issues/39), other than using Linux :)